# how to create two app with a single developer account in FourSquare?

Tags: foursquare

I want to create two different app to get two ClientId and secrete key for my project. Is there any way i can create two app with single developer account in Foursquare?
I don't know its right question to ask on this platform. if not, please enlighten me with correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create only one app with Personal developer account in Foursquare. You need to upgrade to Enterprise developer account to create two apps.

https://enterprise.foursquare.com/upgrade-to-enterprise